# What's a neater way to call multiple transformation methods?

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

I need to call multiple transformation methods on a variable. What are some clean ways to do this in JavaScript? Is it overengineeering it to create a class so I can do method chaining?

Here's an example of what I'd like to tidy up:

```js
let value = 'foo';

value = transformValueFn1(value);
value = transformValueFn2(value);
value = replaceCertainChars(value);
value = encodeAsHtml(value);
// etc 

return value
```

Comment: If you're doing this more than once or twice, a class would make the most sense IMO, though you could also use an array of the functions and `reduce`

Answer (score 1):

Use reduce on array of transformers

```js
let value = 'foo';

const newValue = [
  transformValueFn1,
  transformValueFn2,
  replaceCertainChars,
  encodeAsHtml
].reduce((val, fn) => fn(val), value)


function transformValueFn1(val) {
  console.log('transformValueFn1', val);
  return val;
}

function transformValueFn2(val) {
  console.log('transformValueFn2', val)
  return val;
}

function replaceCertainChars(val) {
  console.log('replaceCertainChars', val)
  return val;
}

function encodeAsHtml(val) {
  console.log('encodeAsHtml', val)
  return val;
}
```

> If you're doing this more than once or twice, a class would make the most sense IMO, though you could also use an array of the functions and reduce – *CertainPerformance*